# simple process rollback question

Tags: java, multithreading, process, parallel-processing, rollback

while revising for an exam, i came across this simple question asking about rollbacks in processes. i understand how rollbacks occur, but i need some validation on my answer.
The question:

[image]
[image]

my confusion results from the fact that there is interprocess communication between the processes. does that change anything in terms of where to rollback? my answer would be R13, R23, R32 and R43. any help is greatly appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to roll back to the point where the process can be consistently restarted.  The inter-process communication means that you cannot have one process recover to after a communication and another to before that communication.

P3 must roll back to R32. So the other processes need to recover back to before any communication which came after that.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense! thanks! so suppose there was no communication between P4 and any process- then P4 could simply rollback to R43, right? as opposed to before where it had to rollback to R32?

Answer (score 0):

There's one rule to follow:  you can't roll back to a point where one process has received a message that hasn't been sent yet.  If you follow that, your global checkpoint will be *consistent*.

Also, you have to decide which processes to roll back.  Don't throw out work if you don't have to.  The only thread you're required to roll back is the faulty one.  Others would roll back only in order to make the checkpoint consistent.

As I see it, one answer to (i)-(iv) will be different from the other three (which will be the same).

Comment: thanks! well, i agree with your point but disagree with your answer. actually, i just had an epiphany- the question says EACH process. the ans should be: i) P1-> R13 ii) P1->R13, P2->R23 iii) P1->r13, P2->R23, P3->R32 iv) P4->R43. would you agree?